# Selecting rows where a column contains at least one character not in a whitelist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm converting some sensitive data from a low-security encryption to a higher security encryption (specifically, from CFMX_COMPAT to AES with a 256-bit key). I intend to encode my AES-encrypted strings using Hex, and CFMX_COMPAT is extremely likely to use special characters, so finding records that aren't yet converted should be as simple as (pseudocode):

```
select from table where column has at least one character not in [A-Z0-9]
```

Is this possible in SQL? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188342.aspx), but I had no idea it was possible in a simple LIKE clause. Awesome!

```
select top 10 foo
from bar
where foo like '%[^A-Z0-9]%'
```